# Dynamically access Hive configs from spark context on spark 2.3

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I am using spark 2.3 (with Hive support enabled) and I want to access and set at runtime the values of some hive configurations, for example `"hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions"`.

If I try to get those from `spark.conf` object, I cannot find them even though they are set, since my code fails later on complaining about a max number of dynamic partitions set to 2000 (the default I find in the hive settings of my cluster)

Is there any way to access hive configs at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that problem you are referring has a solution down below.

[Unable to increase hive dynamic partitions in spark using spark-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43935512/unable-to-increase-hive-dynamic-partitions-in-spark-using-spark-sql)

Comment: yes indeed, but I would be interested in accessing these configs at runtime (and possibly setting them to an higher value without killing the app first)

Comment: Lookslike it's not possible to set it at run time.. I did try using Spark config but seems that it's picking from default hive conf only.. I am not too sure abt setting it at run time using config.

Comment: I also read around this is not possible, even though I cannot find a clear documentation about it. I would like to completely know which params are runtime modifiable and which ones are not